# Ionic Scroll To Specific List Item

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Is there a way to scroll to a specific item in a ion-list?

For example in this codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/grEBQJ

When I Go to test button, I want to scroll to the list item with the text "Text".

```
<button ng-click="goTo()">Go to test</button>

<ion-list class="item">Test</ion-list>
```

I didn't find any examples so goTo is just blank:

```
$scope.goTo = function(){

}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to set an id to list element like :

```
<ion-item id="item{{item.id}}" ng-repeat="item in items">
      Item {{ item.id }}
</ion-item>
```

And then, `$scope.goTo()` method must modify location hash and call `anchorScroll()` method from `$ionicScrollDelegate` service :

```
$scope.goTo = function(id){
     $location.hash('item'+id);
     $ionicScrollDelegate.anchorScroll();
}
```

Check [$ionicScrollDelegate documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicScrollDelegate) for more information.

Update with your codepen : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RadXqL

Comment: You can put this code pen as an example in your answer

Comment: I tried this and did not work at first, but I use `collection-repeat`. Changing it to `ng-repeat` made it work. I changed it in the codepen above to `collection-repeat` and it does work in that example. Hmm, strange.

Comment: If you use native scrolling / overflow-scroll="true", try to disable it.

Comment: Some, how to do this with ionic 3?

Answer (score 5):

I implemented this functionality with JavaScript. After nesting each ion-item in a div element, passed the div element id to the JS function below.

```
scrollTo(element:string) {

      document.getElementById(element).scrollIntoView();

  }
```